# How to correctly use the Angular 14 inject function with multi: true?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular14

I have a service with multiple instances, that I provide multiple.

```
  { provide: MyAbstractService, useClass: MyServiceA, multi: true },
  { provide: MyAbstractService, useClass: MyServiceB, multi: true },
```

For reasons I don't further want to name, I want to use the new inject function to inject those services instead of constructor injection.

Before Angular 14 I would have done that in constructor:

```
@Inject(MyAbstractService) myServices: MyAbstractService[],
```

I expected this to work, but it doesn't:

```
private myServices: MyAbstractService[] = inject(MyAbstractService);
```

inject seems to never return an array, hence I can't assign it to an array type. How to tell inject that I expect an array of services here? Following seems to work, but also seems dirty:

```
private myServices: MyAbstractService[] = inject(MyAbstractService) as unknown as MyAbstractService[];
```

See stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gayhxw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You can pass it as generic argument also: inject<MyAbstractService[]>(MyAbstractService);

Comment: I tried that, but it then says "no overload matches this call" for `MyAbstractService` within `()`

Comment: It looks like the way you were typecasting inject(MyAbstractService) as unknown as MyAbstractService[]; is the way to go for now.

Answer (score 2):

**Using a dedicated token:**

1. Create a dedicated token that represents an array of services using `InjectionToken`:

   ```js
   import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
   export const MY_SERVICES_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<MyAbstractService[]>('MyServices');
   ```
2. Register the service instances in the `providers` array of your module or component using the custom token and the `multi: true` option:

   ```js
   import { MyService1, MyService2 } from './my-services';

   @NgModule({
     providers: [
       { provide: MY_SERVICES_TOKEN, useClass: MyService1, multi: true },
       { provide: MY_SERVICES_TOKEN, useClass: MyService2, multi: true },
     ],
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```
3. Inject the multiple instances of the service using the `inject()` function and the custom token. TypeScript will infer the type of the token, allowing you to access the services in the array:

   ```js
     private myServices: MyAbstractService[] = inject(MY_SERVICES_TOKEN);
   ```

   `myServices` will contain an array of instances for the services registered with `MY_SERVICES_TOKEN`.

**Using a helper**

In my opinion, angular lacks of an `importMultiple` function, if you want to use your base service as a token, here is that helper (typed but dropping the deprecated signature of `inject`)

import-multiple.helper.ts

```js
type InjectParameters<T> = [
  ProviderToken<T>,
  (
    | InjectOptions
    | (InjectOptions & {
        optional?: false;
      })
  )?
];

function assertIsArrayOfServices<T>(value: unknown): asserts value is T[] {
  if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
    throw new Error(`Expected an array but received ${typeof value}, please provide services using multi: true`);
  }
}

export function injectMultiple<T>(...arg: InjectParameters<T>): T[] {
  const services = inject<T>(...arg) as T[];
  assertIsArrayOfServices(services);
  return services;  
}
```

Usage:

```js
private myServices: MyAbstractService[] = injectMultiple(MyAbstractService);
```